# Percentage of a date interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, progress-bar

Via javascript, I want to generate the percentage complete between these two days based on today and I will use this percentage on a jQuery UI progress bar to indicate the time complete or left.

I have tried this formula but I end up always getting 100:

Assume I have two dates:

```
start = new Date(2012,6,2); // Jul 02 2012
end = new Date(2012,6,8); // Jul 08 2012
today = new Date();

alert( Math.round(100-((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%' );
```

How can I achieve this correctly?

Comment: Why bother to instantiate dates at all?  Just use those raw numbers, and then get the current time from your current date with `.getTime()`

Comment: I just get these numbers in Unix timestamp from my server, actually you can ignore the initiation example dates.

Comment: Just fixed the example time instantiates.

Comment: @Hellnar the comments don't match the code.

Comment: @EricG Thank you Eric, fixed code according to the comment.

Comment: if you want to have something like php strtotime functionality in js, see phpjs.org/functions/strtotime/

Answer (score 4):

Since you get unix timestamps from server, you can just do this

```
var start = 1341201600 * 1000,
    end = 1341720000 * 1000,
    now = +new Date;

Math.round(( ( now - start ) / ( end - start ) ) * 100) + "%" //73%
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, especially unix timestamp in mind. Thank you very much Esailija!

Comment: @Hellnar note that you should probably send `now` from server as well. The client's clock can be skewed. If you need to generate it on the client, then you must also take into account the possible skewness on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should be

```
alert( Math.round(100 - (end - today) / (end - start) * 100 ) + '%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to adjust the comment.

```
var start = new Date(2012,6,2); // Jul 02 2012
var end = new Date(2012,8,2); // Sep 02 2012
var today = new Date();

var total = end - start;
var progress = today - start;

console.log( Math.round(progress/ total * 100 ) + "%" );
```

Yields 8% [ 6th of July ]

Comment: The op has fixed the code, it should be start = july 2nd and end = july 8th

Comment: Just remarking that your date values don't match the comment ^^